# How to use grepl function multiple times, in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a vector like `go_id` and a data.frame like `data`.

```
go_id <- c("[GO:0000086]", "[GO:0000209]", "[GO:0000278]")


protein_id <- c("Q96IF1","P26371","Q8NHG8","P60372","O75526","Q01130")
bio_process <- c("[GO:0000086]; [GO:0000122]; [GO:0000932]", "[GO:0005829]; [GO:0008544]","[GO:0000209]; [GO:0005737]; [GO:0005765]","NA","[GO:0000398]; [GO:0003729]","[GO:0000278]; [GO:0000381]; [GO:0000398]; [GO:0003714]")
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(protein_id,bio_process))
```

How can I keep the rows of the `data` for which `bio_process` cell contains at least one of the `go_ids` elements? I note that the GO code can not be repeated in the same `bio_process` cell.

To be more precise, i would like to receive only the first, the third and the sixth row of the data.frame.

I have tried a `for loop` using 'grepl' function, like this:

```
go_id <- gsub("GO:","", go_id, fixed = TRUE)
for (i in 1:6) {
  new_data <- data[grepl("\\[GO:go_id[i]\\]",data$Gene.ontology..biological.process.)]
  }
```

Which I know it can not work because I can not fit in a variable value into a regular expression.

Any ideas on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `grepl`

```
data$ind <-  Reduce(`|`, lapply(go_id, function(pat) 
           grepl(pat, data$bio_process, fixed = TRUE)))

data
#  protein_id                                            bio_process   ind
#1     Q96IF1               [GO:0000086]; [GO:0000122]; [GO:0000932]  TRUE
#2     P26371                             [GO:0005829]; [GO:0008544] FALSE
#3     Q8NHG8               [GO:0000209]; [GO:0005737]; [GO:0005765]  TRUE
#4     P60372                                                     NA FALSE
#5     O75526                             [GO:0000398]; [GO:0003729] FALSE
#6     Q01130 [GO:0000278]; [GO:0000381]; [GO:0000398]; [GO:0003714]  TRUE
```

Comment: I would like to find in which rows the elements of 'go_id' vector exist. It seems that you didnt invlolved the 'go_id' at all.

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki Is your 'go_vector' named as `go_id`

Comment: Yes, my vector is 'go_id'. Thank you

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki Now, I understand where it is having a problem.

Comment: Great! And then we can use someting like this: `new_data <- data[ind == TRUE]`  ?

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki based on your comment, I think you just need a flag to detect if the vecor exist.  The logical column (TRUE/FALSE) would help in that direction

Comment: You can use ``new_data <- data[data$ind,]`` to subset the data after using akrun's method to identifying the rows.

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki IN that case just do a filtering `data1 <- data[data$ind,]`

Comment: @akrun Your code would have the same results, if two of  codes in the vector 'go_id' existing at the same cell of the column 'bio_process' ?

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki yes, it is basically checking `any` elements of the go_id are present.  If you want to check for all the elements, change the `|` to `&` in `Reduce`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl()` :

```
vect <- rep(FALSE, nrow(data))
for(id in go_id){
  vect <- vect | grepl(id, data$bio_process, fixed = T)
}
data[vect,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset using `str_extract` to define the pattern on those substrings that are distinctive:

```
library(stringr)
data[grepl(paste(str_extract(go_id, "\\d{4}]"), collapse="|"),  data$bio_process),]
  protein_id                                            bio_process
1     Q96IF1               [GO:0000086]; [GO:0000122]; [GO:0000932]
3     Q8NHG8               [GO:0000209]; [GO:0005737]; [GO:0005765]
6     Q01130 [GO:0000278]; [GO:0000381]; [GO:0000398]; [GO:0003714]
```

**EDIT**:

The most straighforward solution is subsetting with `grepl`and `paste0` to add the escape slashes for the metacharacter `[`:

```
data[grepl(paste0("\\", go_id, collapse="|"),  data$bio_process),]
```